# form.dispose() always call Validating event and show popup message

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

when i call `form.dispose()` form always calling Validating event and show MessageBox message. 
How can i prevent when `form.dispose()` is executing that Validating event will not fire. I have `MessageBox.Show()` messages in Validating event so they are always on top when `form.Dispose()` is executing.

Is this even possible to prevent on exit? I am using compact framework 3.5

Code:

```
public static void Close<T>(string formName) where T : Form
{
    Form f = null;
    if (Dict.TryGetValue(formName, out f))
    {
        Dict.Remove(formName);
        f.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and Validating event

```
private void acPredmetObravnave_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   if (....)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Error");
   }
}
```

Comment: can you show some code? you should try to close the form before disposing and avoid this message box already on closing.

Comment: yes i want to avoid this message box on form.dispose()

Comment: You could remove the event Handler for the Validating event just before you call f.Dispose();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is:

```
public class MyForm: Form
{
    public InternalClose = false;

    // Your code...


    private void acPredmetObravnave_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InternalClose ) return;
        if (....) MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

And then

```
public static void Close<T>(string formName) where T : MyForm
{
    MyForm f = null;
    if (Dict.TryGetValue(formName, out f))
    {
        Dict.Remove(formName);
        f.InternalClose = true;
        f.Close();
        f.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for idea but i can not call directly InternalClose on generic class. Do you have idea how can i call it?

Comment: @senzacionale: why can't you? If you see I wrote `where T : MyForm`, so your form class with has that property...

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you are explicitly calling Dispose() on form?

You should not call Dispose() before form is closed. This gives you a chance to handle any needed validation on OnClosing or OnClosed events, and disable further validation and message boxes.

Remarks about your code:

- Why is Close method generic?
- You shouldn't hold form references in static dictionary. You may cause a memory leak.
- Before calling Dispose(), disable validation. Try to do this using CausesValidation property to false.
- Alternatively, inside forms, handle OnClosing event and prevent further validation.

Comment: generic is becouse i check which form is opened and which not so i create Dictionary... i call explicitly Dispose() becouse i am using CF and checking which one is opened and which one not.

Comment: so how you suggest calling Dispose()? "You may cause a memory leak.". Are you sure? I am cleaning dictionary on closing...

Comment: From what I see your method doesn't need to be generic. Just remove <T> and related parts. Unless you are holding some open handles to files or data sources which you need to explicitly dispose of, you don't need to call Dispose(). Just disable validation and call Close(). Once no other object holds reference to your form, form will be automatically collected by GC. I'm talking about general practice of connecting objects to other static objects. Some cases are not so obvious. E.g. if you have static method handlers. Pasted code doesn't seem to have anything that would cause mem leak.

Comment: Thx for explain Nikola. You are right i don't nedd generic class for this. I see now that CausesValidation is not supported on CF 3.5

Comment: Ok. In your forms add OnClosing handlers and set private field _closing = true; On Validation event, if (_closing == true) just return without showing message.